# PHP cant conver string that is taken from getElementByid PHP , result is Zero

Tags: php, html, dom

PHP can't read string converted into integer, the result is always 0

can someone help me to solve the code of my php. please help me..

```
<html> 
    <body>
        <div id='div1'></div>
        <div id='div2'>
            <H2>demo string to integer </H2>
            <p> the example of value is <span style="font-style: italic;">12</span> </p>
        <?php $shtm="<div id='a'>12</div>" ;?>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>

<?php
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($shtm);
$div = $doc->getElementById("a");

$nval= $div->ownerDocument->saveHTML($div);

echo '1. result before converted :'. $nval .'</br>';
echo '2. using gettype : '. gettype($nval) .'</br>';
echo '3. convert to integer using (int) :' . (int)$nval.'</br>';
echo '4. try using intval function :' .intval($nval) .'</br>'; // it should be 13 but the result is the same 
echo '5. try adding with 1 : '.(int)$nval+1; // it should be 13 but the result is error A non well formed numeric value encountered 

?>
```

I need the value that can be access in php normal string and int value
I expected the output is what i expected, not zero

Comment: `$div->nodeValue` - https://3v4l.org/aiHMu

Answer (score 0):

It's unuseful if you just want to get the content of a node :

```
$nval= $div->ownerDocument->saveHTML($div);
```

You can simply do :

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($shtm);
$div = $doc->getElementById("a");
echo 'div[id="a"] contains ', $div->textContent;
```

Comment: my goal is to take the real STRING value of "a" element.

Comment: Give a better example of what you want